# How to use browser working js script in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'd like to use online working scripts on my local client, but can't find a way to make it working.

For example, let's take this script:

https://bscscan.com/jss/EVM.js?v=21.8.4.1

I can unminify it, but it has window variable that is only for browser.

How can I convert it to run in nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Window doesn't exist within the nodejs context, however, it you need to use this lib you could consider using jsdom to utilize it.

See here: [JSDom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)